# How to add style to android app

Tags: android, css, html, android-styles

I'm wondering how I could add styles to my android applications. I have created some apps on Eclipse but all of them with fixed style. I would like to know how people manage to create those fancy and cool apps that you can download from the GooglePlay. I would like to know if there is any tool for applying style to buttons, tabs, etc like a CSS to HTML.

I hope no to bother anyone with this questions, I'm eager to know how to do it ^^

Comment: You can find here about styles http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html and you can create custom buttons like here http://www.devahead.com/blog/2011/08/creating-a-custom-android-button-with-a-resizable-skin/   you can find some design basics here: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-user-interface-design-relative-layouts/  and here http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_linear-layouts_2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like to use PhoneGap (http://phonegap.com/), it lets you code your entire app with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Go with Fries. It's a design framework specifically for Android, and it provides all the fancy bottons, tabs, etc: http://jaunesarmiento.me/fries/

Comment: Fries is no longer maintained as stated in their GitHub repository: https://github.com/jaunesarmiento/fries

Answer (score 0):

If you want to style your native app (Android and iOS) using the CSS language, I'm aware of two options:

1. **FreeStyle**: former Pixate, *Free* - http://www.freestyle.org/
2. **NativeCSS**: *Paid* - https://nativecss.com/